# Concatenate 2 text elements on a line with full-width border using CSS only

Tags: css, text

I'm working with some WordPress code (WooCommerce plugin, to be exact), and I'm trying to format a line of code in a sidebar so that 2 separate text items (one in a `<a`>, the other in a `<span`> are all on the same line, the full width of the column, and with a bottom border.

It looks something like this (except the bottom border on each text do not go all the way across the enclosing sidebar box).

Here's the code fragment I'm trying to live with (i.e. I don't want to change it):

```
<div class="widget">
  ...
  <ul class="product-categories">
    <li class="cat-item">
      <a href="http://localhost/dalluva/shop/product-category/books/">Books</a>
      <span class="count">(5)</span>
    </li>
    ...
```

And here's the CSS I have now:

```
.widget ul li a {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    line-height:1.0;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 22px;
    display: inline-block;
 }

.widget ul li span {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
   line-height: 1.0;
   padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

The output in the image above looks right for this CSS code, but when I change the 'span' CSS to include a width:100%, it causes the span element to wrap to the next line, looking like this:

http://www.dalluva.com/temp/browse-catalog-2.JPG

I've played with white-space: nowrap, overflow: hidden, etc., but I can't seem to find a way to have both the `<a`> and the `<span`> text on the same line with the border extending the full width of the column.

Comment: The border should be applied to the container `<li>`, not the `<a>` and `<span>`.  I'd like to see more of the other CSS/markup, though to give a full answer as both `<a>` and `<span>` are already "inline" tags, something else is causing them to wrap (like a restrictive width on a container).

Comment: Hi Sumo -- normally, yes, it would be applied to the <li>, but in the real example the LI elements are nested with other UL/LI sets, so I can't see an easy way to use CSS to generate a full-width bottom border on *every* line.  Here's the full code block for the widget (generated by a wordpress catagory walk).  http://jsfiddle.net/michaelhpdx/xYUhJ/13/  I haven't yet extracted all of the actual CSS that is formatting the above code -- it's a b*tch to extract with lots of cascading.

Comment: I've fully corrected my answer I gave earlier and unfortunately, I have failed to do it without strictly CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Remove following style from `.widget ul li span` and `.widget ul li a` with implementation of `width:100%`

```
display: inline-block;
```

check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VZkVu/1/)

Comment: Hi Usman -- thanks for the fiddle, but it doesn't look like it's working.  I've created a fiddle as well that illustrates the problem. I need the bottom border of the A and SPAN elements to be the full width of the DIV container it is in.  See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/michaelhpdx/pLeZb/6/

Comment: i made another fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/pLeZb/10/ it might be helpful to you..

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: I have fully corrected my answer.**

Unfortunately, I think you need to use some jQuery to inject some containers as I was not able to find away to have the bottom border extend to the edge of the container `div` without it.  Here's what I came up with.  You can see a demo of it with [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4xSn/117/).

**CSS**

```
.widget ul.children {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.widget .border {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
}

.widget span.count {
    padding-left: 3px;   
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".widget ul li").each(function() {
        $(this).children().slice(0, 2).wrapAll("<div class='border'></div>");
    });​
});
```

Given your HTML, I've assumed I can select the first two children of the `li`, then wrap those tags in a block element (in this case a `div`).  Using that block element, I can now style it with a border.  Since a `div` is automatically 100% the width of its container, it gives you the border extending to the limits of `.widget`.

Comment: Hi Sumo -- I hadn't considered using Javascript, but it's quite a clever solution.  Thanks for working on this, I'll try and integrate into my site and report back.  Cheers.

Comment: @MichaelHorne This was a tough nut to crack and I tried everything without jQuery.  There just wasn't enough markup for me to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

#### Do not give spaces between `</a>` and `<span>`:

```
<a href="http://localhost/dalluva/shop/product-category/books/">Books</a><span class="count"> (5)</span>
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pLeZb/7/

***PS:** Don't use floats for such small things.*

#### In case you won't be able to edit HTML, then use proper method for clearing floats:

```
.widget ul li span {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
   line-height: 1.0;
   padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
 }

.cat-item {overflow: hidden;}
.cat-item a, .cat-item span {float: left; display: inline;}​
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pLeZb/8/

Comment: Hi Praveen -- thanks, but I can't directly modify the HTML as it's auto generated by a widget block that I don't want to edit (and have to maintain).  The spaces between the A and SPAN are here to stay. :-).

Comment: @MichaelHorne Then we can use a proper clearing of floats. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/pLeZb/8/ Will update in my answer too!